# How to conditionally disable an item template field in a Gridview?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

```
private void hidePartPayment()
{
    foreach (GridViewRow row in invoices.Rows)
    {
        var cb = (CheckBox)row.FindControl("Check");
        if (!cb.Enabled)
        {
            //row.Cells[12]. this is not working
            row.Cells[12].Enabled = false;   
        }
    }
}
```

I have a popup window on a gridview, I want to disable the link based on the condition above (non clickable) but is not working.

Comment: show the function you call to open the popup window.

Comment: thank for the reply but I am to figure out using this approach

and in the C#

 LinkButton rowval = row.FindControl("id") as LinkButton;
                    rowval.Visible = false;

Comment: whats your gridview linkbutton markup? ie, how did you create the linkbutton inside the gridview?

Answer (score 1):

Did you debug the code? Does your code come to the point

```
row.Cells[12].Enabled = false;
```

Then please check the column `row.Cells[12]` in quick watch. May be its not correct row your are pointing.

Comment: Yes!! thanks for the reply, I'm able to solve it at the backend in C#